# How to change hotkey for Visual Studio 2022's Intellicode Auto Completion

Tags: visual-studio-2022, intellicode

By default, Visual Studio 2022's IntelliCode Auto Completion works by pressing the Tab key.
Unfortunately that prevents you from using the Tab key to insert whitespace, leading to suggestions like this:

[image: suggestion is not indented]

In order to avoid this, I'd like to change the key used to apply the whole line completion to a different key, but I can't find it in the Tools/Environment/Keyboard keyboard mapping menu.
Does anyone know how to change this key?

Comment: The feature I am referring to is the IntelliCode Whole Line Completion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/visual-studio-whole-line-completions
IntellISense as I understand it is the dropdown menu, not the suggestion provided for whole line completion.

Comment: My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You could either turn off all or parts of IntelliCode (`Tools`->`Options...`->`IntelliCode`) or press the `ESC` key to cancel the suggestion and then press the `TAB` key. See the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/visual-studio-whole-line-completions#accept-or-dismiss-whole-line-completions) for more details.

You can change the Whole line completion to the right arrow if that is better. There doesn't seem  to be any way to choose your own key though.

Comment: There is no 'Intellicode' listed in 'Tools > Options' in the Community Edition of VS 2022 that I'm using.

Comment: Of course, there is. I am using VS 2022 ver.17.7.6 and if you check Tools > Options, there will be IntelliCode section in the tree on the left. Alternatively, you can use the Search box in the VS title bar. Type "IntelliCode" there.